# Add an existing vm to vagrant global environment

Tags: vagrant

Something happened and I no longer have any vagrant boxes in my global environment. In other words:

```sh
$ vagrant global-status
id       name   provider state  directory
--------------------------------------------------------------------
There are no active Vagrant environments on this computer! Or,
you haven't destroyed and recreated Vagrant environments that were
started with an older version of Vagrant.
```

I can still change directories into the directory with the `Vagrantfile` and run `$ vagrant up && vagrant ssh` but it's a little annoying.

I'd rather not do a destroy because I'm afraid of losing all of my data. Is there any other way of getting these vm's back into my global environment? Thanks!